# How to find the size of padding added by SVG preserveAspectRatio

Tags: css, svg, snap.svg

Given an image that is centered by SVG preserveAspectRatio, how do I find out how much padding it was added around the image to center it?

I need to superimpose some other image on top of an existing image that was centered with preserveAspectRatio: xMidYMid. Unless I know what the boundaries of the image are I can't paint something on top of it.

Below is a simple example: http://jsfiddle.net/ddehghan/zz4ppyhe/

```
var s = Snap("#svg");

var image = s.image('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/2/24/Lenna.png', 
                0, 0, '400px', '200px')
.attr('preserveAspectRatio', "xMidYMid meet");
```

[image]

**Update:**

unfortunately getBBox() see: http://jsfiddle.net/zz4ppyhe/3/ does not return the position of the image but rather the blue line which includes the white space. I think this same problem exists in CSS as well. when the image is centered or moved by the underlying layers there is no interface to the the final location from Javascript.

Comment: Only thing that springs to mind, is post the image hidden as an html img element, get the read width/height of it, and based that the aspect ratio is fixed, calculate the displayed width & height, and subtract the difference from the svg. Very fiddly though, and it feels like there should be an easier way.

Comment: yeah. I hope there is a better way. But I searched through all properties of snap.svg and I couldn't find anything that looks promising.